# Distinct not working in select database from another server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, distinct

I have this select here:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT cod_arq, 
           (SELECT description FROM [serverTwo].[perg].dbo.marc_section WHERE paragraph = 10 AND cod_arq = AC.cod_arq) AS author,
           (SELECT description FROM [serverTwo].[perg].dbo.marc_section WHERE paragraph = 24 AND cod_arq = AC.cod_arq) AS title,
           (SELECT description FROM [serverTwo].[perg].dbo.marc_section WHERE paragraph = 25 AND cod_arq = AC.cod_arq) AS edt
    FROM [serverTwo].[pergamarc].dbo.marc_section AC
) AS ACN
WHERE ACN.author IS NOT NULL 
    AND ACN.title IS NOT NULL
```

I tested some sql from serverOne to serverTwo and it's ok, I can call them from one server to another.
But this sql above works just fine if I run it on the "serverTwo" (means the the sintaxe is correct), but not if I run it from the serverOne. But if I remove the DISTINCT keyword, it works (showing duplicated rows, but works).

What could be happening with this DISTINCT? Maybe some COLLATE conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT acn.*
FROM (SELECT ac.cod_arq, 
           MAX(CASE WHEN paragraph = 10 THEN description END) as author,
           MAX(CASE WHEN paragraph = 24 THEN description END) as title,
           MAX(CASE WHEN paragraph = 25 THEN description END) as edt
      FROM [serverTwo].[pergamarc].dbo.marc_section AC
      GROUP BY ac.cod_arq
     ) AS ACN
WHERE ACN.author IS NOT NULL AND ACN.title IS NOT NULL;
```

The subquery is not strictly necessary.  You can use a `HAVING` clause instead.

Comment: I worked!! But why it worked without group by when I was running it on "serverTwo"?